# Integrating OAuth2 Login for Swagger API with firebase auth

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-authentication, fastapi

```py
class AuthenticationMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    """Middleware to authenticate requests using Firebase Auth.
    """

    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next: Callable):
        # This is where you can modify the request if needed
        path = request.url.path
        # Exclude specific paths from middleware
        if path in [
            "/health",
            "/auth/login",
            "/docs",
            "/openapi.json",
        ]:
            return await call_next(request)  # Continue with the request

        headers = request.headers
        token = headers.get("Authorization")

        if not token:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Authorization token is missing")

        try:
            # Verify and decode the token using Firebase Admin SDK
            user_info = auth.verify_id_token(token)
            # Check if the token is still valid
            if user_info.get("exp") < time.time():
                raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Token expired")
            # If the token is valid, you can access user information
            request.state.user = user_info
            return await call_next(request)  # Continue with the request

        except Exception as err:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid token") from err
```

I have written a middleware above - which basically tries to find the firebase token from the headers. The problem that I see here is that for any API that does use a token, I need to use postman/thudnerclient.

I'm interested in integrating a user-friendly OAuth2 login directly into the Swagger UI for easier testing. I've come across the FastAPI documentation on simple OAuth2 (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/#see-it-in-action), and I'm wondering if there's a way to adapt this for my Firebase authentication middleware.

Could someone guide me on incorporating OAuth2 login into the Swagger UI for FastAPI, allowing seamless token testing directly within the Swagger interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
from fastapi.security import OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer

oauth2_code_bearer = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
    authorizationUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
    tokenUrl="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    scopes={"openid": "email"}, # or whatever you want
)

# use as dependency
async def auth_required(
    oauth2_code_bearer: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Security(oauth2_code_bearer),
) -> None:
    ...
```

You will need to pass `client_id` and `client_secret` from Google Cloud Console. But yet no [proper token refresh](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7257) and you can't specify `client_id` and `client_secret` within the configuration code AFAICT

---

Also you can inherit your authentication middleware from [`starlette.middleware.authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://www.starlette.io/authentication/) instead of `BaseHTTPMiddleware` to make use of `request.user`

Comment: Oh this is cool af, but I do have one doubt, does firebase use OAUTH2 under the hood then? Or does firebase use its ouwn auth?

Comment: It depends on what authentication you are using, but if it is a proper client side oauth2, then only configuration should change. These links [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/openid-connect#before_you_begin) [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) might be helpful

Comment: I used url paths from this [.well-known](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) configuration. It should be the same structure for other oauth providers

Comment: Awesome, do you have any repositories that I can look at that has this?